# Why do I get an error when launching Django server in MacOS?

Tags: python, django, macos

I just started using Django for a web app project and I am going through the Elasticsearch in Django but when I run the `python manage.py runserver` command from the defualt mysite directory I get the following error:

```
zsh: abort python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: did you solve it? I am getting the same issue, but no idea how to fix

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and solved it updating this library:

```
brew uninstall asn1crypto   (uninstall current outdated version)
brew install asn1crypto     (install new version, 1.3.0 up)
```

Comment: are you sure? here is no asn1crypto at brew

Comment: Totally, I fixed the same problem in two different computers, actually.

Comment: It worked for me as pip uninstall asn1crypto (current version for me is asn1crypto-0.24.0) and installed the latest version by pip install asn1crypto (installed asn1crypto-1.4.0). in mac Catalina and am using pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at a solution for the problem:

If you're using a virtual environment

`cd venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

`rm -rf asn1crypto`

Then things will be working back.

If you're not using a virtual env, remove it from system site-packages

`cd /usr/local/bin/python3.7/site-packages`

then remove it the same way above.

It appears to be a compatibility issue with OSX Catalina, issue posted on [GitHub October 30th, 2019](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/44996)